# awk retain adjacent line based on duplicate field

Tags: awk, duplicates

I am processing some output of tshark fields. Some processing has already occurred and there are now adjacent rows where the last field is duplicated. These duplicates are missing a row with a matching sequence number. The task is to keep only pairs of adjacent rows where the sequence column matches. The last field has values of 0 and 130 and each pair of rows starts with 130. Sequence is a number 0-15. The data stream contains many rows.
The fields are:

```
date       time                 src-int dst-int seq     function
24/01/2017 16:57:27.307400000   10      1000    11      130
24/01/2017 16:57:27.418675000   1000    10      11      0
24/01/2017 16:58:53.603604000   1000    10      12      0
24/01/2017 16:58:54.121603000   10      1000    13      130
24/01/2017 16:58:54.677752000   10      1000    14      130
24/01/2017 16:58:54.681079000   1000    10      14      0
24/01/2017 17:09:12.974979000   10      1000    1       130
24/01/2017 17:09:12.981149000   1000    10      1       0
24/01/2017 17:09:13.477211000   1000    10      2       0
24/01/2017 17:09:14.026279000   1000    10      3       0
```

The desired output is to keep pairs of rows with the function order 130 then 0 and matching sequence number:

```
24/01/2017 16:57:27.307400000   10      1000    11      130
24/01/2017 16:57:27.418675000   1000    10      11      0
24/01/2017 16:58:54.677752000   10      1000    14      130
24/01/2017 16:58:54.681079000   1000    10      14      0
24/01/2017 17:09:12.974979000   10      1000    1       130
24/01/2017 17:09:12.981149000   1000    10      1       0
```

I have a solution that half works. It matches `\t130$` and gets the next line, printing if sequence matches. It returns good data however it doesn't handle duplicate values of 130. In the example data it omits sequence 14. The number of adjacent duplicate rows is arbitrary so it seems silly to nest another test.

```
awk "/\t130$/ {seq=$5; prev=$0; getline;} $5==seq {print prev; print;}"
```

How best to handle all duplicates on the start condition?

BTW, using GNU awk in Windows 7. 
FWIW the two rows will ultimately be concatenated using `print prev,$0`, not shown for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk 'p==$5 && q==130 && $6==0 {print b $0} {p=$5; q=$6; b=$0 "\n"}' file
24/01/2017 16:57:27.307400000   10      1000    11      130
24/01/2017 16:57:27.418675000   1000    10      11      0
24/01/2017 16:58:54.677752000   10      1000    14      130
24/01/2017 16:58:54.681079000   1000    10      14      0
24/01/2017 17:09:12.974979000   10      1000    1       130
24/01/2017 17:09:12.981149000   1000    10      1       0
```

- `p` is previous `$5`, should be the same as current `$5`
- `q` is previous `$6`, should be 130
- `b` buffers the previous `$0` and a `\n` is appended to is for pretty `print`

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the flow, I believe the second `{action}` is always executed since it has no condition? In which case why clear b? Also, any reason for appending a line end rather than using two print statements?

Comment: 1. Sloppiness. 2. Non particular.

Comment: This answer enforces that the match must be in the adjacent line. Marking as correct as it's the most precise fit to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR==1 { print; next } 
    $6 == 0 && $5 == seq && c == 0 { print row; print; c++ }
    $6 == 130 { seq=$5; row=$0; c=0 }
' file
date       time                 src-int dst-int seq     function
24/01/2017 16:57:27.307400000   10      1000    11      130
24/01/2017 16:57:27.418675000   1000    10      11      0
24/01/2017 16:58:54.677752000   10      1000    14      130
24/01/2017 16:58:54.681079000   1000    10      14      0
24/01/2017 17:09:12.974979000   10      1000    1       130
24/01/2017 17:09:12.981149000   1000    10      1       0
```

Comment: Thanks, I like it and easily modified to concatenate the rows.What is the purpose of `NR==1 { print; next }`? Using this solution on the input given results in the omission of the row with seq 11 function 0. If I delete the NR==1 section it works fine.

Comment: @gloopy NR==1 part is just for printing title. you can remove that if not needed

Comment: aah. Header row provided for problem description only :)

Comment: This answer matches any following line ending in 0 with a matching sequence number, prior to finding the next 130, and does not strictly enforce the adjacent row requirement. It works with the data set and the subtle difference could be very useful.

Comment: @gloopy i have added adjacent row requirement